# How has Foucault and post modernism in general become the dominant lense of analysis in Western Academia and how do Hegelians and others oppose that?

Tags: hegel, postmodernism, foucault, derrida, zizek

I have read of the strong impact of Foucault (the most cited author ?) and post-modernist lenses in particular in Academia. From Edward Said's Orientalism to Spivak's work (which even doe was a response to Foucault) applies deconstruction in interpreting the world through discourses. Along with that many mainstream works in humanities such as Gender Trouble, Capitalist Realism etc. all view reality through the Deleuzian/Foucauldian/Derridan perspective. Why has PoMo come to dominate academia ? What is the opposition of Hegelians(like zizek) to that lense ? What are other competing lenses like ofc Marxisme being another one.

Comment: Two opposing trends in Continental philosophy are the Marxist/Hegelian [Frankfurt school](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frankfurt_School), and recently popular [speculative realism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_realism) with its critique of "correlationism", to which [Foucault is assimilated](https://deontologistics.co/2009/08/26/critique-and-correlationism/), although this assimilation is controversial:"*I think this is just a very poor reading of Foucault which assimilates his position to the Wittgensteinian one*".

Comment: @Conifold The text is critical of Foucault's position being assimilated into a Wittgensteinian one *with regards to the discarding of metaphysics*, though. When it comes to the theoretical consequences for the *hermeneutical circle* and how lifeworld, conceptualisation, and language formation are intertwined, I would deem it valid to put them into the same box, as it were. I'd be more critical of labelling this box with "correlationalism", as the positions can be seen as a kind of epistemological monism with different modes of access and that's the reason for *meta*physics being meaningless.